# how to change the ui on urwid

Tags: python, urwid

I am creating a small `urwid` app for my use, the structure is a `Filler` which has a `Pile` composed of several `Text` filed, followed by a `Divider`, an `Edit`, another `Divier` and finally a `Text`:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
Divide
>> Edit
Divide
Textout
```

Now, I want to replace `Text1 .. Text3` with other `Text` field, the exact number of those varies. I figure I should redraw the entire UI, but I got no response on `draw_screen()`

My class:

```
class main_ui(urwid.Filler):
  def __init__(self):
      self.body = welcom()
      self.options = self.body.options
      self.replay = self.body.replay
      self.ask = self.body.ask
      super(main_ui,self).__init__(self.body.pile,valign='top')
  def paint(self):
      super(main_ii,self).__init__(urwid.pile[urwid.Text('test')])
```

The `welcom()` function generates the above fields, and `options` is `dict` that holds information I need

I run the loop like this

```
def refresh(_loop,_data):
    m.new_point()
    _loop.draw_screen()
    _loop.set_alarm_in(2,refresh)


m = main_ui()
loop = urwid.MainLoop(m)
loop.set_alarm_in(2,refresh)
loop.run()
```

How can I update my ui?